# how to add callback function with prototype validation.js in magento

Tags: validation, magento, prototypejs, prototype

I want to extend form validation prototype class (MagentoRoot/js/prototype/validation.js) and want to add an callback function with that. I know in below code snippet 4th parameter is for callback function, but I don't know how to pass(syntax) that callback function as a 4th parameter.

```
Validation.addAllThese([
    ['validate-select-custom', 'Please select an option.', function(v) {
                return ((v != "none") && (v != null) && (v.length != 0));
    },<callbackfunction>],
```

Actually, I want to execute my custom code after validation failed/passed, so for that I want to add callback function with validation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look @ https://github.com/atetlaw/Really-Easy-Field-Validation

Comment: thanks R.S, but it's not much helpful for me because I am not much familiar with prototype script. Can you please let me know how to pass callback function name as a parameter in given code snippet?